How to access connection string with python
I have this local.settings.json in my local Azure function (Timer trigger)
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    .
    .
    .
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "sql_server": "valid connection string"
  }
}

I managed to access the connection string locally using:
conn = os.environ["ConnectionStrings:sql_server"]
and my code runs okay.
But, when I deploy I get 'Failure Exception: KeyError: 'sql_server' [...] getitem raise KeyError(key) from None'.
I tried to execute in portal changing that line to:
conn = os.environ["sql_server"]
But nothing changed.
Does anyone know how I can call this method on Azure Web?

Do you get similar error when you try to to access other fields? For example, IsEncrypted

No, when I try to access to environment variables setted in 'App Settings' (not in 'Connection Strings') I get them by using os.environ["variable"]

Add the connection string in this way and also refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-connection-strings doc.


Values stored under ConnectionStrings in local settings file needs to be added in connection string section of function app. I have added a test value of type SQLServer as shown below.



To access this values in function app, you need to add prefix based on the connection types. below are the prefixes for the different connection types. Refer MSDoc.



SQLServer:  SQLCONNSTR_
MySQL:  MYSQLCONNSTR_
SQLAzure:  SQLAZURECONNSTR_
Custom:  CUSTOMCONNSTR_
PostgreSQL:  POSTGRESQLCONNSTR_
Notification Hub:  NOTIFICATIONHUBCONNSTR_
Service Bus:  SERVICEBUSCONNSTR_
Event Hub:  EVENTHUBCONNSTR_
Document Db:  DOCDBCONNSTR_
Redis Cache:  REDISCACHECONNSTR_



As I have used SQLServer connection type, so SQLCONNSTR_ is to be amended along with the connection string name.
I am accessing the value using os.environ['SQLCONNSTR_test_sql_server_connectionString'] in code and able to get the expected value.



You need to use the prefix along with the connection string name based on its type in order to fetch the value in function app.


It works, thank you very much!!
